# Как получить значение боковой кнопки мыши в GetAsyncKeyState?

Tags: c++, winapi

Всем привет, у меня есть вопрос. Есть проверка через if() где через GetAsyncKeyState назначается кнопка при нажатии которой будет срабатывать функция. Вопрос какое значение у верхней бокой кнопки мыши (mouse4)? Или есть ли оно вообще? Значение которое находится на месте 'c'.

```
            if (GetAsyncKeyState('C'))
            {
                *(int*)(localPlayer + m_iObserverMode) = 1;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать VK_XBUTTON1 и VK_XBUTTON2
Т.е

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1))
{
...
}
else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_XBUTTON2))
{
...
}
```

Коды кнопок с 6 и далее же рассматривай как ввод с клавиатуры, т.к RAWMOUSE поддерживает только 5 кнопок (об этом можно почитать [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawmouse)).